# Why does this loop go forever?

Tags: c, for-loop

```
int main() {
        for(3;2;1)
            printf("hello\n")
}
```

I thought this loop wouldn't even be executed. AFAIK we have to define a variable; put a condition; increase/decrease. However in this code none of the things I counted exists. So I think this program should crash. But it goes on forever.

Comment: What do you base your hypothesis on?

Comment: AFAIK we have to define a variable; put a condition; increase/decrease. However in this code none of the things I counted exists. So I think this prpgram should crash. But it goes forever as I didnt expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> AFAIK we have to define a variable; put a condition; increase/decrease. However in this code none of the things I counted exists. So I think this program should crash. But it goes on forever.

While learning about `for` loops you were likely exposed to a very specific use of a loop, and therefore extrapolated about what may or may not appear there syntactically. But you didn't get the whole picture. There is a standard for that C language, and it is that standard which defines how a loop may be written and how it will behave. For a loop, we may look at [§6.8.5](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5) (Iteration statement) to determine the correct behavior:

```
  iteration-statement:
          while ( expression ) statement
          do statement while ( expression ) ;
          for ( expressionopt ; expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
          for ( declaration expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
```

That's the grammar for all loops. See how the `for` loop allows an arbitrary expression in all 3 places? Since even `1`, `2`, and `3` are expressions in C, they can go there. And the standard even tells us what the behavior should be:

> An iteration statement causes a statement called the loop body to be executed repeatedly until the controlling expression compares equal to 0.
>
> The statement
>
> ```
> for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
> ```
>
> behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the controlling expression that is evaluated before each execution of the loop body.

So `2` must be evaluated, and compared equal to 0. Which will never occur, hence the behavior you observed.

Answer (score 4):

Because the exit condition (2) is always true.

This works because the format of a `for` statement is

```
for (clause-1;expression-2;expression-3)
```

Where `clause-1` can be a declaration (e.g. `int i = 0`) or an expression.

In your case you have three expressions, so the statement is still syntactically valid.

The loop exits when `expression-2` evaluates to false (0) which, in your case, it never does since it's a non-zero constant (2).

Comment: How ia it always true? I mean why?

Comment: I expanded my answer. See if it's clearer now. If it's not, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

The stopping conditional expression `2` is never zero.

So the loop runs forever.

Answer (score 2):

C is not Bourne shell like in `for i in 3 2 1 ; do echo hello ; done`

The proper loop is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
        for(int i = 1; i <=3 ; i++)
            printf("hello\n");
}
```

Here, the conditional expression `i <= 3` isn't always true like `2` is.  True is any non-zero value.

Comment: How is 2 always true? There is no condition there.

Comment: @ÖmerKural In C, any non-zero value is True.

Answer (score 1):

we know `0` is false and `1` is true. In this case, in conditional statement `for( ;2;)` is always true like `while(2)`. so it will run infinitely.
.

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop doesn’t *require* the use of any variables. It simply specifies the use of three *expressions*, each of which may be optional:

```
for ( expression-1opt ; expression-2opt ; expression-3opt ) statement
```

First, *expression-1* is evaluated (if it is present).  This expression typically initializes the condition we’ll test for in *expression-2*, but it doesn’t *have* to.

Next, *expression-2* is evaluated.  If the result of the expression is non-zero, then the loop body will be executed.  If *expression-2* is not present, then it’s implicitly replaced with a `1`.

After the loop body has been executed, *expression-3* is evaluated.  This expression typically updates the condition we test for in *expression-2*, but again, it doesn’t *have* to.

Repeat the last two steps until *expression-2* evaluates to zero.

In the case of `for ( 1; 2; 3 ) ...`, `2` evaluates to non-zero, so the loop body executes.  Since that value never changes, the loop runs “forever”.  You get the same result with `for (;;)`.